# Bad Primary Chunk '/dev/chunk1317'?

Tags: informix

After migrating a informix binaries to new server by os level cloning there was a warning when I execute the oninit -vy like could not open some chunks. then I ask system administrator link those missing chunks and again executed the oninit -vy again it prompt a warning with mentioning those chunks are bad chunks. what is the reason behind that. Is there any mistake happen when chunks re-configuring to new server

```
nwnhost@nwn$oninit -vy
Reading configuration file '/informix/strim/inf11/etc/onconfig'...succeeded
Creating /INFORMIXTMP/.infxdirs...succeeded
Checking config parameters...succeeded
Allocating and attaching to shared memory...succeeded
Creating resident pool 1629910 kbytes...succeeded
Allocating 6606044 kbytes for buffer pool of 2K page size...succeeded
Allocating 19267600 kbytes for buffer pool of 8K page size...succeeded
Creating infos file "/informix/strim/inf11/etc/.infos.ocs_test"...succeeded
Linking conf file "/informix/strim/inf11/etc/.conf.ocs_test"...succeeded
Initializing rhead structure...succeeded
Writing to infos file...succeeded
Initialization of Encryption...succeeded
Initializing ASF...succeeded
Initializing Dictionary Cache and SPL Routine Cache...succeeded
Bringing up ADM VP...succeeded
Creating VP classes...succeeded
Forking main_loop thread...succeeded
Initializing DR structures...succeeded
Forking 1 'soctcp' listener threads...succeeded
Starting tracing...succeeded
Initializing 128 flushers...succeeded
Initializing SDS Server network connections...succeeded
Initializing log/checkpoint information...succeeded
Initializing dbspaces...succeeded
Opening primary chunks...Bad Primary Chunk '/dev/chunk1186'.
Bad Primary Chunk '/dev/chunk1188'.
Bad Primary Chunk '/dev/chunk1265'.
Bad Primary Chunk '/dev/chunk1279'.
Bad Primary Chunk '/dev/chunk1317'.
Bad Primary Chunk '/dev/chunk1319'.
Bad Primary Chunk '/dev/chunk1320'.
succeeded
Validating chunks...succeeded
Initialize Async Log Flusher...succeeded
Starting B-tree Scanner...succeeded
Init ReadAhead Daemon...succeeded
Initializing DBSPACETEMP list...succeeded
Checking database partition index...succeeded
Initializing dataskip structure...succeeded
Checking for temporary tables to drop...succeeded
Updating Global Row Counter...succeeded
Forking onmode_mon thread...succeeded
Creating periodic thread...succeeded
Creating periodic thread...succeeded
Starting scheduling system...succeeded
Verbose output complete: mode = 5
```

here is the onstat -d output for those chunks

```
nwnhost@nwn$onstat -d | egrep 'chunk1188|chunk1186|chunk1265|chunk1279|chunk1317|chunk1319|chunk1320'
7be211028        1252   36     48         2097125    0                     PD-B-- /dev/chunk1186
7be211428        1254   36     48         2097125    0                     PD-B-- /dev/chunk1188
7be22d028        1331   37     48         2097139    0                     PD-B-- /dev/chunk1265
7be22fc28        1345   38     48         2097000    0                     PD-B-- /dev/chunk1279
7be241228        1383   48     48         2097139    0                     PD-B-- /dev/chunk1317
7be241628        1385   38     48         2097139    0                     PD-B-- /dev/chunk1319
7be241828        1386   37     48         2097000    0                     PD-B-- /dev/chunk1320
nwnhost@nwn$
```

Comment: On the face of it, it means that you have 7 chunks which are mirrored chunks (probably) that have valid mirror chunks but invalid primary chunks.  I'm inferring that the Informix server was able to come up because the mirror chunks were valid — but you'll need to find out what happened to those chunks and fix them.  There's another possibility — these aren't mirrored chunks at all, but the server came up even though it spotted the problems.  Either way, you need to review the structure of the server.

Comment: It appears that your `$INFORMIXDIR` is `/informix/strim/inf11`.  You should find a file `/informix/strim/inf11/etc/oncfg_ocs_test.NNN` where `NNN` is the server number as 1-3 decimal digits.  That should contain information about the dbspace, chunks and logical logs associated with your server instance.  You can validate the contents against what you've recovered.  AFAIK, there isn't a standard tool to do that validation — other than the server itself, of course.

Comment: Also, if you're still using Informix 11.x (11.10, 11.50, 11.70), you should be planning to upgrade — probably to 14.10, but definitely to 12.10.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is there any addtional information can obtain from `/informix/strim/inf11/etc/oncfg_ocs_test.NNN` than `onstat -d` output. I check that file . anyway I noticed that those chunks are consumed by data according to onstat -d. I need know is there any mistake happened from system admin side when he map the chunks? or anyother possible reason for this kind of message .I added the output of onstat -d for that chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve above error by opening those chunks by below command.

```
onspaces -s  [dbspace_name] -p [pathname] -o [offset] -O
```

eg :-

```
onspaces -s  dbspace1 -p /dev/chunk1186 -o 96 -O
```